# Why would I need more than one event loop with Python's asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

`asyncio` functions, for example `asyncio.gather` or `asyncio.ensure_future` accepts loop as optional agrument. But all examples I saw use single loop and never pass loop argument.

Is there a point in using more than one (default) loop simultaneously? How often is it used in production?

Is it a valid example — having special loop working on another CPU cores or GPU for numeric calculations in C code (which doesn't acquire GIL)? Or special loop running tasks in UI thread?

Comment: Isn't that parameter there so you can use a 3rd party implementation (i.e. not two loops, but a different loop)?

Comment: @thebjorn Indeed, there are different implementations event in Python standard library but one can be set as default with `asyncio.set_event_loop`. But special parameter and the fact `asyncio` implementation checks that tasks passed to `asyncio.gather` have same loop suggest that there may be more than two loops in single Python program.